# How to solve: Error using horzcat Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent

Tags: matlab, matrix, concatenation

Everything is fine in the concatenation step. When I am saving these variables (each variable has size 30x180) and I am labeling it in the Labeling step, I got this error, help with this?

What I want is to add the label number to each row of the feature matrix `Class1`.

> ```
> Error using horzcat
> Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.
> Error in CONCAT (line 16)
> dlmwrite(strcat('E:\Matlab Projects\FER\Features\','.txt'), [Class1 1] , 'delimiter', '\t','-append','roffset',0,
> 'precision', 4);
> ```

```
% Concatenation Step
class1 = cat(2,(load(fullfile('.', 'Features', 'ANG1.txt'))), (load(fullfile('.', 'Features', 'ANG11.txt'))));

% Labeling Step
dlmwrite(strcat('E:\Matlab Projects\FER\Features\','.txt'), [Class1 1] , 'delimiter', '\t','-append','roffset',0, 'precision', 4);
```

Comment: Why do you do `[Class1 1]`? What is the purpose? This is what MATLAB is complaining about, because `1` and `Class1` don't have the same number of rows.

Comment: no iam using 1:7 for labeling its fine in other file : dlmwrite(strcat('E:\Matlab Projects\FER\Features\',int2str(num_of_feat),'.txt'), [Features_V(x,:) 1] , 'delimiter', '\t','-append','roffset',0, 'precision', 4);
i want to access the class1 values like Features_V(x,:)

Comment: Ah, I think I understand what you want now. I've edited your question to include this. You can [edit] your question at any time to improve and clarify it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a matrix `Class1` or arbitrary size, adding a `1` at the end of each row is accomplished as follows:

```
nrows = size(Class1,1);
[Class1 ones(nrows,1)]
```

The `ones` function creates a matrix with ones, of the requested size. Here, we're using the number of rows in `Class1`, so that the two matrices have the same number of rows and can be concatenated.

In general, to add an arbitrary number `n`, you can do either:

```
[Class1, ones(nrows,1) * n]
```

or:

```
[Class1, zeros(nrows,1) + n]
```

or:

```
[Class1, repmat(n,nrows,1)]
```

Comment: thanks i figured it out. i made one file of features along with labels. if know any tools to classify in face recognition or expression then let me know please. i will be very grateful.